# sccm 2012 r2 some reports return error

Tags: report, sccm

I recently upgraded from SCCM 2012 SP1 to SCCM 2012 R2. There are some issues with some reports not working (also SMS_PORTALWEB_CONTROL_MANAGER returns errors, but that may not be related). I had some WMI corruption issues on the server, had to run a restore from wmimgmt.msc and have not had WMI errors in the eventlog since. However the reporting issues persist.

Will insert error message here as i cannot attach a file.

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'S-1-5-21-304347872-1734857272-171853879-7318' to data type int.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.GetReportParameters(String Report, String HistoryID, Boolean ForRendering, ParameterValue[] Values, DataSourceCredentials[] Credentials, ReportParameter[]& Parameters)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.GetReportParameters(String Report, String HistoryID, Boolean ForRendering, ParameterValue[] Values, DataSourceCredentials[] Credentials, ReportParameter[]& Parameters)

-------------------------------
Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.SmsException
An error has occurred during report processing.


Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ParameterPresenter.GetParameters()
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ParameterPresenter.LoadParameters(IReport report, Collection`1 navigationParameters, IResultObject resultObject)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ReportViewerPresenter.Worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)

-------------------------------

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'S-1-5-21-304347872-1734857272-171853879-7318' to data type int.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.GetReportParameters(String Report, String HistoryID, Boolean ForRendering, ParameterValue[] Values, DataSourceCredentials[] Credentials, ReportParameter[]& Parameters)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005.GetReportParameters(String Report, String HistoryID, Boolean ForRendering, ParameterValue[] Values, DataSourceCredentials[] Credentials, ReportParameter[]& Parameters)


Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ParameterPresenter.GetParameters()
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ParameterPresenter.LoadParameters(IReport report, Collection`1 navigationParameters, IResultObject resultObject)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ReportViewerPresenter.Worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)

-------------------------------





Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportServerException
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)


Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReportSoapProxy.OnSoapException(SoapException e)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String Report, String HistoryID)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ReportViewerWindowsForms.SetParameterValues_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)

-------------------------------

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportServerException
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)


Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReportSoapProxy.OnSoapException(SoapException e)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String Report, String HistoryID)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ReportViewerWindowsForms.SetParameterValues_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)

-------------------------------

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportServerException
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'S-1-5-21-304347872-1734857272-171853879-7318' to data type int.


Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReportSoapProxy.OnSoapException(SoapException e)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String Report, String HistoryID)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.SrsReporting.ReportViewerWindowsForms.SetParameterValues_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)

-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall the Reporting Point role & use built-in reports created after that (not old ones which could be preserved after role reinstall).